# How to get the bit value of an IP address in C?

Tags: c

I need to output the 32-bit value of an IP address (an example IP address: 208.40.244.65) in C. Don't know what this means, or how to do it?

Comment: What is the structure of your IP Address

Comment: divided into 4 parts each part is 8 bits

Comment: Google is your friend: https://www.google.com.au/#q=c%2B%2B+convert+ip+address+to+binary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming IPv4,

```
const char* ip_addr_str = "208.40.244.65";  // In hex, D0.28.F4.41

uint32_t ip_addr_num;
inet_aton(ip_addr_str, (struct in_addr*)&ip_addr_num);
```

The above copies the bytes exactly how they would be found in an IP packet, so the result varies by machine. You'll either get

```
0xD028F441  // Big-endian machines
```

or

```
0x41F428D0  // Little-endian machines
```

Follow up with the following to normalize to `0xD028F441`:

```
ip_addr_num = ntohl(ip_addr_num);
```

Note: I think `inet_aton` actually accepts domains as well as IP addresses.

Comment: int inet_aton(const char *cp, struct in_addr *inp);  considering i pass my IP address as the first argument, what would be the second?

Comment: Sorry for the numerous edits. I seem to be more tired than I thought!

Answer (score 0):

It means that you convert the four bytes in the ip adress into a 32 bit integer. Like this:

```
uint32_t val32 = rightMostByte | (byte2 << 8) | (byte3 << 16) | (byte4 << 24);
```

Comment: This is the code i have that returns the separate values of the IP address but I wasn't able to figure out how to store these values individually                                                                                                      
 char* c;
  c = strtok(IPaddress, ".");
  while(c != NULL){
         int a = atoi(c);
         printf("%d\n", a);
         c = strtok(NULL, ".");
}

Comment: I would argue you want the result you posted on both BE and LE machines.